# Erro ao executar projeto Hello World com condigo padrão do eclipse CDT

Tags: c++, mingw

Estou tentando utilizar o codigo padrão que vem no projeto Hello World no Eclipse CDT(estou usando minGW), porém, quando eu coloco para rodar o projeto não aparece nada no console, somente que a aplicação foi terminada.

Inicialmente, aparecia um erro chamado: eclipse: *** No rule to make target 'Hello.o', needed by 'Hello.exe'.
Então, eu recriei o projeto e tentei dar play novamente e, apesar da mensagem Hello World ainda não aparecer no console, o erro que antes aparecia simplesmente desapareceu.[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Não sei muito como as coisa funcionam no eclipse mas vou tentar te ajudar.

Você criou um projeto e adicionou o arquivo PQ.cpp, este arquivo esta no mesmo diretório do projeto? se sim olhe o makefile e veja se ele está incluído nele, se não tente colocar na mesma pasta do projeto.

O console ao qual você se refere é o cmd do windows ou um próprio do eclipse? por que é bem estranho ele ter gerado o .exe e nao ter mostado o hello world.
se for o do eclipse é provavelmente o problema acima.

O código em si está certo, se por acaso você quiser mudar de IDE use o codeblocks.

Comment: Olhe no Makefile se tem essa flag -subsystem,windows e remova,talvez resolva.